# Notification for new version of the application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have just developed my first app. Now, I want to put notification or alert facility by which if new version is available in Google Play store then User comes to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Using google cloud messaging service. You can send notification to all user which are using 
your apps

Comment: Thank you. and is there any way by which I force user to install new app ?

Comment: nope their are no such ways that you can forcefully install update.